# URL Rewrite rule in website does not cover all cases

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I have read every thread I can find on this, and I cannot figure out why this rule doesn't work all of the time.  As it sits right now, the rule redirects everything to https://domain.com.  This includes other domain aliases that I have, as well as removing the www and adding the https.

However, when I go to https://www.domain.com the rule fails to remove the www.  Can anyone help me out with this?

```
    <rule name="SecureRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?(.*)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://domain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

I am running on IIS 7.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Choose some possible input and simulate in your mind what happens when they come. Then you will see the rule you created is almost useless in many scenarios, as its conditions are too simple.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on that.  I am not extremely familiar with how these things work.  A reply that says "Think about it" is not really helpful.